# How do I find breaks in multiple date ranges with Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, range, date-range

Let's say I have the following date ranges in Ruby:

> Sat, 01 Jan 2011..Tue, 01 Feb 2011
>
> Wed, 05 Jan 2011..Thu, 17 Feb 2011
>
> Wed, 02 Feb 2011..Tue, 01 Mar 2011
>
> Sun, 01 Jan 2012..Thu, 05 Jan 2012

By what process can I take all four of these ranges and get output that tells me there is a break in the ranges on Wed, 02 Mar 2011?

**EDIT**
Sergio is right and there appears to be nothing built in. I can grok this like so:

```
x = Range.new(Date.parse('2011-01-01'), Date.parse('2011-02-01'))
r = Range.new(Date.parse('2011-01-05'), Date.parse('2011-02-17'))
y = Range.new(Date.parse('2011-02-02'), Date.parse('2011-03-01'))
z = Range.new(Date.parse('2012-01-01'), Date.parse('2012-01-05'))

ranges = [x,y,z,r]

dates = ranges.collect!{|r|r.to_a}.flatten!.uniq!.sort!

dates.delete_if do |date|
  index = ranges.index(date)
  next_date = ranges[index + 1]
  next_date == date + 1 || next_date.nil?
end
```

Still looking for the best solution though.

Comment: There's no built-in function that does this. Try to figure out something.

Comment: what is "a break in the ranges"? maybe you can put together some valid Ruby code with assertions.

Comment: ok, you probably mean "what date starts a gap in the ranges"? but what if the ranges create several gaps, you want only the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's [`Enumerable.chunk`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) is useful here. I shortened the ranges being checked for simplicity, and added an additional range that was out of order, to show that it's handling out of order ranges:

```
require 'date'

date_ranges = [
  '01 Jan 2011', '03 Jan 2011',
  '02 Jan 2011', '04 Jan 2011',
  '02 Mar 2011', '03 Mar 2011',
  '01 Jan 2000', '02 Jan 2000'
].each_slice(2).map{ |dates| 
  Range.new( 
    *dates.map{ |d| 
      Date.parse(d) 
    } 
  ) 
}

gaps = date_ranges
  .inject([]){ |a, d| a |= d.to_a }   # accumulate the unique dates in the ranges
  .sort                               # sort to get them in ascending order
  .each_with_index                    # add an offset into the order
  .chunk{ |d,i| d - i }               # group by the delta
  .to_a[1 .. -1]                      # grab all but the first group
  .map{ |g,dates| dates.first.first } # strip off the groups and indexes

puts gaps
```

Outputs:

```
2011-01-01
2011-03-02
```

Because I added the out of order range, the original starting range is now a gap, as is the March 02 2011 date.

This will give you an example what `chunk` is doing:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each_with_index.chunk{ |n,i| n-i }.to_a # => [[1, [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3], [5, 4]]]]
[1,2,  4,5].each_with_index.chunk{ |n,i| n-i }.to_a # => [[1, [[1, 0], [2, 1]]], [2, [[4, 2], [5, 3]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Array arithmetic:

```
date_ranges = [
  '01 Jan 2011', '03 Jan 2011',
  '02 Jan 2011', '04 Jan 2011',
  '02 Mar 2011', '03 Mar 2011',
  '01 Jan 2000', '02 Jan 2000'
].each_slice(2).map{ |dates| 
  Range.new( 
    *dates.map{ |d| 
      Date.parse(d) 
    } 
  ) 
}

dates = date_ranges.collect{|r| r.to_a}.flatten

((dates.min..dates.max).to_a - dates).min
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach that would be something like (completing this left as an exersize for the reader):

```
class DateRange
  def initialize (start, end)
    ...
  end

  def interection (range)
    # Determine the intersection of the current range and another
    # Returns either nil or a new DateRange object.
    ...
  end

  def expand (range)
    # Expand the current range to include the passed in range
    ...
  end
end

class DateRangeSet
  include Enumerable

  def <<(range)
    # Inspect the current ranges, and any that have an intersection, merge them
    ...
  end

  def each
    @ranges.each { |r| yield r }
  end
end
```

Assuming your `input` is an array of `[start,end]` arrays, something like:

```
coll = DateRangeCollection.new
input.each { |s, e| coll << DateRange.new(s,e) }
puts "Gaps found!" if coll.to_a.count > 1
```

That being said... Maybe there's a more succinct way?